# Subprocess in Spyder, matplotlib and prints do not work

Tags: python, matplotlib, subprocess, spyder

Running this on a regular console works well, but from Spyder the window does not show up. Prints neither btw.

main.py:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("test.py", shell=True)
```

test.py:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,3,2])
plt.show()
```

I am using Spyder 3.3.3, python 3.7.3 on windows 10

Github issue tracker: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/9113

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Are you on Windows?

Comment: yes, windows 10, spyder 3.3.3

Comment: I imagined that. We hide `subprocess` generated cmd windows on Windows because some packages (e.g. pyomo) generate hundreds of those windows while running. Please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) so we don't forget to make that configurable in our next release.

Comment: yes I will, It works with PyQt5 windows though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in spyder 4,

Option to show windows in a subprocess:

`Tools` > `Preferences` > `IPython Console` > `Advanced Settings` > `Windows adjustments`